# A module which is a sum of a family of minimal submodules is a direct sum of a subfamily

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm trying to solve an exercise of Musili's *Introduction to Rings and Modules*:

> Let $M$ be a module which is a sum of a family $\{N_i:i\in I\}$ of 
>   distinct minimal submodules. Then show that $M$ is a direct sum of a
>   subfamily $\{N_j:j\in J \subseteq I\}$. Furthermore, give an example
>   for which $I$ is infinite but $J$ is finite. (Hint: Apply Zorn's 
>   lemma to $$\mathcal{F}:=\left\{K\subseteq I:\sum_{k\in K}N_k=\bigoplus_{k\in K} N_k\right\}$$ ordered by set inclusion.

**My attempt.** Let $\mathcal{F}$ as defined in the hint. $\mathcal{F}\neq \emptyset$ since every singleton subset of $I$ is in $\mathcal{F}$. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a chain in $\mathcal{F}$. I could check that the union of all elements of $\mathcal{F}$ in $\mathcal{C}$, that is, $$\mathcal{U}:=\bigcup_{C\in \mathcal{C}} C$$ is a upper bound in $\mathcal{F}$. Then, we can really evoke Zorn's lemma and state that $\mathcal{F}$ contains a maximal element, say $\mathcal{A}$. Now I guess I have to prove that $$M=\bigoplus_{a\in \mathcal{A}} N_a,$$ being $\subseteq$ the nontrivial part. But I couldn't get it. I think now it's the time to use the minimality of the submodules. If someone could help me with this proof, and maybe with the solicited example as well, I'd be grateful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got it. Following the reasoning above, suppose that an element $x\in M$ is not in $$\bigoplus_{a\in \mathcal{A}} N_a.$$ Then, by hypothesis, $x\in N_b$, a minimal submodule of $M$, for some $b\in I\backslash\mathcal{A}$. Since $x\neq0$ and $N_b$ is minimal, $N_b=(x)$. Note that the intersection of $(x)$ and the direct sum of the submodules $\{N_a: a\in \mathcal{A}\}$ is $(0)$. Therefore, $\mathcal{A} \cup \{b\}\in \mathcal{F}$, a contradiction by the maximality of $\mathcal{A}$ in $\mathcal{F}$.